# Can I put margin to a container element in Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles, margin

I'm wondering if I can define the margin of children, in the parent.

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
childrenMargin="10dp"
>
 <child />
 <child />
 <child />
</LinearLayout>
```

or do I have to set `layout_margin` for children?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add padding to the parent element.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp" >

     ...

</LinearLayout>
```

One way to think about is that **padding is the inner spacing of a View** (that is, the space between it and its children), while **margin is the outer spacing of a View** (the space between it and its parent and neighbors).

Comment: Thanks, but I have background in children, so I need to specify padding separately. So I need margin, but I'm just wondering if I can pass it from the parent to the children.

Comment: If you absolutely must have a margin, then you must set it manually;  there's no way to specify attributes for all children.

However, even if use margin instead of padding, the background of the child elements will still conform to the margin; you'll get the same results.